# AutoCompleteTextView filtering multiple words over the same string

Tags: android, filtering, autocompletetextview

There is a way to make AutoCompleteTextView filter suggestions by separated words? The normal behaviour of that control is filtering by the entire string you write. I'll show you an example. We have the next words on the adapter (they will be the suggestions):

```
String[] words = {"foo bar bla bla ", "foo bla bla bar"};
```

If we write at the input `"foo bar"`, the suggestion will be the index 0 of the array of words `"foo bar bla bla"`, because the text matches as substring of the input.

My question is: There is a way to filter the input `"foo bar"` as separately words ? (by space, in this case, but it would be a comma, asterisk or whatever), making the AutoCompleteTextView filter the suggestion that matches `"foo"` **and** `"bar"`.

For the example I said, it would show the both strings of the array as suggestion, because they contains `"foo"` and `"bar"` as substring.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code:

```
       AutoCompleteTextView text;
       MultiAutoCompleteTextView text1;
       String[] words = {"foo bar bla bla ", "foo bla bla bar"};

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
              text1=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

              ArrayAdapter adapter = new 
                 ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,words);

              text.setAdapter(adapter);
              text.setThreshold(1);

              text1.setAdapter(adapter);
              text1.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
           }
```

or
Please refer to [Android - Auto Complete](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm)

Comment: I've tried already the MultiAutoCompleteTextView but it dont works the way I'm looking for. It separates the text by tokens, but only find for suggestions for the last token. The behaviour I want to achieve is showing suggestions by filtering **all** the tokens, not only the last one. I've made a test, and you can see in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/OzQvQHR.png) how it's filtering only for the last token `"red"`.